# Does a power series of a functional expression need to coincide with its Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

It is about a function $a(\epsilon)$ which depends on a variable $\epsilon$. At some point, the author was able to show, that $a$ needs to be an implicit function of $\epsilon$, i.e. differentiable and $F(\epsilon,a(\epsilon))=0$ in some neighborhood of $\epsilon=0$.

Now, the interesting part is, that another argument implies that the function $a(\epsilon)$ can be expressed as a power series with respect to $\epsilon$. What does this exactly mean? Does this already imply, that $a$ needs to be smooth and the power series of $a(\epsilon)$ coincides with the Taylor series of $a$? Or is there just another function $\alpha$, such that the Taylor series of $\alpha$ corresponds with the power series of $a(\epsilon)$ with respect to $\epsilon$?

The author states at some point, that there is a Taylor series of $a$. But as I said, we only know, that $a$ is differentiable from the implicit function theorem. I am a bit confused about this, so any hint or help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any function defined by a power series *with a positive radius of convergence* is automatically smooth in the open disk of convergence and coincides with its Taylor series there.